# What technology allows the Raspberry Pi Zero to be used as a USB device?

Tags: usb, pi-3, pi-zero

I have seen lots of people using their Raspberry Pi Zero as a USB device by connecting it to a host computer via USB and are able to SSH into it locally (https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/overview)

However,  this cannot be done the Raspberry Pi 3 or any other of the RP boards. So I am wondering what feature does the Zero have, that allows this to work, but is missing in the RP 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raspberrypi 0 has a [USB OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) port which can act as a host or a client, unlike regular USB ports which can only be one of those. Or in the case of charging only ports neither host or client.

Answer (score 3):

RPi boards other than Zero cannot connect to a host computer via USB because data pins on their microUSB connectors are not connected to anything. Here's a screenshot of RPi 3 schematics:

[image]

Comment: OTG pins cannot be routed to USB-A ports, only to microUSB. All broadcom chips have OTG capability, Pi-zero is unique exactly because those pins are routed.

Comment: I recall reading about connecting a normal rpi to a host with an A-A connection.

Comment: @jiggunjer This only works with Pi A, and requires a non-standard cable.